# Integrating Outlook appointment with windows application using c#

Tags: c#-4.0

Hi i am developing a windows application in c#.net where i need to show the appointments created in outlook should be able to visible in my windows application. I am not having any idea even how to start and where to start. Please help me out with this issue what i am facing. Please give me some references where appointments of outlook are integrated in windows applications using c#.net

Answer (score 0):

**Integrating Outlook using C#** here you will have some reference to go for your answer http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rambab/OutlookIntegration10282006032802AM/OutlookIntegration.aspx

also a question from SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630409/integrating-pocket-outlook-and-c-sharp-application)